# Ignore case when matching file name extensions with find

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a bash script a while back that resizes and compresses all images in directory with Image Magick.

```
# Usage: smartResize "2400x2400>"                                                                                                                  
function smartResize() {                                                                                                                    
    find ./ -name "*.jpg" -exec magick mogrify -resize $1 -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -interlace JPEG -quality 85 -colorspace RGB {} \;   
    find ./ -name "*.JPG" -exec magick mogrify -resize $1 -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -interlace JPEG -quality 85 -colorspace RGB {} \;   
    find ./ -name "*.jpeg" -exec magick mogrify -resize $1 -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -interlace JPEG -quality 85 -colorspace RGB {} \;  
    find ./ -name "*.JPEG" -exec magick mogrify -resize $1 -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -interlace JPEG -quality 85 -colorspace RGB {} \;  
}
```

I had to add extra lines to find some alternative cases for `.jpg` extensions. Which I don't particularly like but got the job done.

Does anybody have a better idea of how to handle case sensitivity and the optional `e` in `jpeg` extensions?

*n.b. I'm running this in Cmder: Git Bash on Windows.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GNU` versions of `find` have an `-iname` flag which enables case insensitive matching of file name globs,

```
find ./ -iname '*.jpg'
```

or if you are on a system without `GNU` utilities, use the bracket expressions to the glob

```
find ./ -name '*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]'
```

If you are interested in multiple name filters, just use the `-o` expression for including multiple name globs

```
find ./ \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" \)
```

Comment: You can also add multiple `-name` flags is the extensions differ.

Comment: Thanks this works great. I'm now trying to suss out the optional `[Ee]` alternative for completion

Comment: @Sarcoma: Sure, happy you found that useful. But it was a duplicate of an existing question. Marking it as such

Comment: No problem, thanks for the help

Comment: @Sarcoma: Use 123's suggestion add an extra `-name ` filter. See my update

Comment: Ended up with a combination of both `\( -name "*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]" -o -name "*.[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]" \)`